# ViewportControl equivalent for winrt

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, controls

In my wp8 silverlight app I use the [MediaViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneMediaViewer/) control for displaying / swiping through pictures. Now I'm trying to port my app and the MediaViewer control to winrt for windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1.

The images are rendered in a ViewportControl. This control is not available in winrt. What can I use to replace this control?

Some code:

```
<ViewportControl x:Name="Viewport">
    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas">
        <mediaViewer:ThumbnailedImageViewer 
                          x:Name="ZoomableContent"
                          CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                          RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
            <mediaViewer:ThumbnailedImageViewer.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ZoomableContentTransform"/>
            </mediaViewer:ThumbnailedImageViewer.RenderTransform>
        </mediaViewer:ThumbnailedImageViewer>
    </Canvas>
</ViewportControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ScrollViewer`, Windows Runtime's version of this control is much more powerful than Silverlight's one.
Handle `ViewChanged` event and read `VerticalOffset` and `HorizontalOffset` properties to get offsets. You can use `ChangeView()` method to scroll to a horizontal or a vertical offset.
In addition, you can easily add zooming :)